# Laravel controller Merge 2 array to Comparision selling

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 array to get the sold products from location at different date ranges then I need to make comparison between the two arrays

```
$results_day_report = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
        ->select(DB::raw('b.name as business_location_name , t.location_id as location_id , tsl.product_id as product_id , p.name as product_name , tsl.variation_id as variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS total'))
        ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
        ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
        ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
        ->whereRaw("t.transaction_date LIKE '$reportdate%'")
        ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
        ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
        ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
        ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
        ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
        ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('b.id', 'asc')
        ->get(); 
        
        $results_day_report_year_before = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
        ->select(DB::raw('b.name as business_location_name , t.location_id as location_id , tsl.product_id as product_id , p.name as product_name , tsl.variation_id as variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS total'))
        ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
        ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
        ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
        ->whereRaw("t.transaction_date LIKE '$reportdate_year_before%'")
        ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
        ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
        ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
        ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
        ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
        ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('b.id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

and Now I have results to be
$results_day_report =

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4170 ▼
  #items: array:23 [▼
    0 => {#4172 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 526
      +"product_name": "سيارات تصادم (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 674
      +"quantity": "15.0000"
      +"total": "300.00000000"
    }
    1 => {#4178 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 528
      +"product_name": "قطار اطفال (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 676
      +"quantity": "5.0000"
      +"total": "50.00000000"
    }
    2 => {#4179 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 529
      +"product_name": "ارنوب (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 677
      +"quantity": "3.0000"
      +"total": "30.00000000"
    }
    3 => {#4173 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 594
      +"product_name": "جم رجال يومى ع.د"
      +"variation_id": 742
      +"quantity": "3.0000"
      +"total": "90.00000000"
    }
    4 => {#4171 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 595
      +"product_name": "جم رجال يومى ق.م"
      +"variation_id": 743
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "60.00000000"
    }
    5 => {#4177 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 597
      +"product_name": "جم رجال شهرى ع.د"
      +"variation_id": 745
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "200.00000000"
    }
    6 => {#4175 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 615
      +"product_name": "رسم استخراج كارنيه اول مره"
      +"variation_id": 763
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "30.00000000"
    }
    7 => {#4180 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 637
      +"product_name": "جلسة مساج مشتركين"
      +"variation_id": 785
      +"quantity": "2.0000"
      +"total": "400.00000000"
    }
    8 => {#4181 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 679
      +"product_name": "جيم سيدات يومى ع د"
      +"variation_id": 827
      +"quantity": "2.0000"
      +"total": "70.00000000"
    }
    9 => {#4182 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 681
      +"product_name": "جيم  سيدات يومى مدنى"
      +"variation_id": 829
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "85.00000000"
    }
    10 => {#4183 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 683
      +"product_name": "جيم سيدات  شهرى ق م"
      +"variation_id": 831
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "450.00000000"
    }
    11 => {#4184 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 705
      +"product_name": "حمام سباحة مغطى(م)"
      +"variation_id": 853
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "75.00000000"
    }
    12 => {#4185 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Subscriptions"
      +"location_id": 20
      +"product_id": 773
      +"product_name": "العاب ثابته"
      +"variation_id": 921
      +"quantity": "3.0000"
      +"total": "30.00000000"
    }
    13 => {#4186 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 6140
      +"product_name": "الترامبولين م"
      +"variation_id": 6291
      +"quantity": "7.0000"
      +"total": "70.00000000"
    }
    14 => {#4187 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 6568
      +"product_name": "كاروسيل (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 6719
      +"quantity": "5.0000"
      +"total": "50.00000000"
    }
    15 => {#4188 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 7781
      +"product_name": "مصارعه سومو"
      +"variation_id": 7932
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "217.39100000"
    }
    16 => {#4189 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 7782
      +"product_name": "تيلي جيمز"
      +"variation_id": 7933
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "217.39100000"
    }
    17 => {#4190 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 7783
      +"product_name": "فولي بيج بول"
      +"variation_id": 7934
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "347.82600000"
    }
    18 => {#4191 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 7784
      +"product_name": "سوكر شوز"
      +"variation_id": 7935
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "347.82600000"
    }
    19 => {#4192 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 7785
      +"product_name": "الساعة"
      +"variation_id": 7936
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "434.78300000"
    }
    20 => {#4193 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 9091
      +"product_name": "اكستريم جيم سيدات شهري مدني"
      +"variation_id": 9251
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "800.00000000"
    }
    21 => {#4194 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 9341
      +"product_name": "ارشيرلي فايت"
      +"variation_id": 9501
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "434.78300000"
    }
    22 => {#4195 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Red Zone"
      +"location_id": 44
      +"product_id": 9342
      +"product_name": "كومبو (2)"
      +"variation_id": 9502
      +"quantity": "10.0000"
      +"total": "2000.00000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

and result of $results_day_report_year_before to be

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4174 ▼
  #items: array:15 [▼
    0 => {#4196 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Video Game"
      +"location_id": 18
      +"product_id": 513
      +"product_name": "موتوسيكل"
      +"variation_id": 661
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "15.00000000"
    }
    1 => {#4202 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Video Game"
      +"location_id": 18
      +"product_id": 517
      +"product_name": "هزازات"
      +"variation_id": 665
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "10.00000000"
    }
    2 => {#4203 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Video Game"
      +"location_id": 18
      +"product_id": 520
      +"product_name": "هدايا كبيرة"
      +"variation_id": 668
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "20.00000000"
    }
    3 => {#4197 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 526
      +"product_name": "سيارات تصادم (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 674
      +"quantity": "24.0000"
      +"total": "480.00000000"
    }
    4 => {#4176 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 527
      +"product_name": "سامبا (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 675
      +"quantity": "2.0000"
      +"total": "40.00000000"
    }
    5 => {#4201 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Gaming Area"
      +"location_id": 19
      +"product_id": 528
      +"product_name": "قطار اطفال (مايكل)"
      +"variation_id": 676
      +"quantity": "4.0000"
      +"total": "40.00000000"
    }
    6 => {#4199 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 594
      +"product_name": "جم رجال يومى ع.د"
      +"variation_id": 742
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "30.00000000"
    }
    7 => {#4204 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Lavandula Gym"
      +"location_id": 17
      +"product_id": 598
      +"product_name": "جم رجال شهرى ق.م"
      +"variation_id": 746
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "350.00000000"
    }
    8 => {#4205 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 615
      +"product_name": "رسم استخراج كارنيه اول مره"
      +"variation_id": 763
      +"quantity": "5.0000"
      +"total": "50.00000000"
    }
    9 => {#4206 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 688
      +"product_name": "جم رجال يومى ع.د"
      +"variation_id": 836
      +"quantity": "2.0000"
      +"total": "70.00000000"
    }
    10 => {#4207 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 690
      +"product_name": "جم رجال يومى مدنى"
      +"variation_id": 838
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "85.00000000"
    }
    11 => {#4208 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 691
      +"product_name": "جم رجال شهرى ع.د"
      +"variation_id": 839
      +"quantity": "3.0000"
      +"total": "750.00000000"
    }
    12 => {#4209 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Tiba Rose Gym"
      +"location_id": 16
      +"product_id": 692
      +"product_name": "جم رجال شهرى ق.م"
      +"variation_id": 840
      +"quantity": "1.0000"
      +"total": "450.00000000"
    }
    13 => {#4210 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Subscriptions"
      +"location_id": 20
      +"product_id": 763
      +"product_name": "حجزملعب س/ط س ن"
      +"variation_id": 911
      +"quantity": "4.0000"
      +"total": "560.00000000"
    }
    14 => {#4211 ▼
      +"business_location_name": "Subscriptions"
      +"location_id": 20
      +"product_id": 773
      +"product_name": "العاب ثابته"
      +"variation_id": 921
      +"quantity": "2.0000"
      +"total": "20.00000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

then I make this foreach loop to generate one array with the comparison

```
foreach($results_day_report as $result_day_report)
    {
        array_push($queries, (object)[
                'business_location_name' => $result_day_report->business_location_name,
                'location_id' => $result_day_report->location_id,
                'product_id' => $result_day_report->product_id,
                'product_name' => $result_day_report->product_name,
                'variation_id' => $result_day_report->variation_id,
                
                'quantity_report_date_same_year' => $result_day_report->quantity,
                'total_report_date_same_year' => $result_day_report->total,
                
                'quantity_report_date_year_before' => 0,
                'total_report_date_year_before' => 0,
                
                'quantity_date_range_same_year' => 0, 
                'total_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                
                'quantity_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                'total_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                
                'step_a' => '1',
            ]);
    }
    foreach($results_day_report_year_before as $result_day_report_year_before)
    {
        $collection = collect($queries);
        if(!$collection->contains('variation_id', $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id))
        {
            array_push($queries, (object)[
                'business_location_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->business_location_name,
                'location_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->location_id,
                'product_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_id,
                'product_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_name,
                'variation_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id,
                
                'quantity_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                'total_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                
                'quantity_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->quantity,
                'total_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->total,
                
                'quantity_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                'total_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                
                'quantity_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                'total_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                
                'step_b' => '1',
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($result_day_report_year_before) {
                if($item->location_id == $result_day_report_year_before->location_id && $item->variation_id == $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id)
                {
                    $item->quantity_report_date_year_before = $result_day_report_year_before->quantity ;
                    $item->total_report_date_year_before = $result_day_report_year_before->total ;
                    $item->step_b = 2 ;
                }
                elseif($item->location_id != $result_day_report_year_before->location_id && $item->variation_id == $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id)
                {
                    array_push($queries, (object)[
                        'business_location_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->business_location_name,
                        'location_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->location_id,
                        'product_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_id,
                        'product_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_name,
                        'variation_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id,
                        
                        'quantity_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                        'total_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                        
                        'quantity_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->quantity,
                        'total_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->total,
                        
                        'quantity_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                        'total_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                        
                        'quantity_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                        'total_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                        
                        'step_b' => '3',
                    ]);
                }
                return $item;
            });
            
        }
    }
```

Now the result of final array ($queries) will be

[image]

This result isn't correct, the correct answer must be array with 34 object not 33 object
Error at step of array push which contain 'step_b' => '3' , it return null not correct object

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem on my code

the correct code is

```
$collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($result_day_report_year_before ,&$queries) {
                if($item->location_id == $result_day_report_year_before->location_id && $item->variation_id == $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id)
                {
                    $item->quantity_report_date_year_before = $result_day_report_year_before->quantity ;
                    $item->total_report_date_year_before = $result_day_report_year_before->total ;
                    $item->step_b = 2 ;
                }
                elseif($item->location_id != $result_day_report_year_before->location_id && $item->variation_id == $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id)
                {
                      array_push($queries, (object)[
                        'business_location_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->business_location_name,
                        'location_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->location_id,
                        'product_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_id,
                        'product_name' => $result_day_report_year_before->product_name,
                        'variation_id' => $result_day_report_year_before->variation_id,
                        
                        'quantity_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                        'total_report_date_same_year' => 0,
                        
                        'quantity_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->quantity,
                        'total_report_date_year_before' => $result_day_report_year_before->total,
                        
                        'quantity_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                        'total_date_range_same_year' => 0,
                        
                        'quantity_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                        'total_date_range_year_before' => 0,
                        
                        'step_b' => '3',
                    ]);
                }
            });
```

The error was in using the array in the map function

Thanks